# How can I know which version of .Net is using an application in IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, net

We have migrated an application from Net version 3.5 to 4.8. The truth is that we are encountering many problems. Everything seems right, but it doesn't seem to work returns a 500 error without any more information. My approach is that it is not running with the correct version of Net. Therefore, install version 4.8 of the following link: [Net 4.8 Framework](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-offline-installer-for-windows-9d23f658-3b97-68ab-d013-aa3c3e7495e0) for Windows Server 2016. It still don´t working. I still have my doubts, how can I know which version of Net 4.8 is using my application, considering that I do not have access to Windows Features?

Could you check this information from here?

[image: Configuration APP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot verify it from there.  That is the Common Language Runtime (CLR) version. All versions of .NET 4 have the same CLR version, 4.0.30319.  Note that the CLR version is separate from the .NET release version. A system can have only one version of .NET 4.

To control if your application uses .NET 3 or .NET 4, you may use the `supportedRuntime` element of the `startup` element of the app.config file, AKA .config.  Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <!--supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/-->
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where is allocated this file? I only can see a web.config in my application. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kenzo_Gilead: web.config is another name for the file.

Comment: My application has different web.config. I choose the first one, in parent folder. It doesnt have startup section so I added under configuration but the issue still happens... Any other idea to try? :)

Comment: @Kenzo_Gilead: Idea for what? That is the one and only way to specify the runtime vesion.

Comment: Ah, ok. I meant if you have any random idea to try to resolve the issue itlsef. Sorry again. I rate your answer.